# I cannot add a Web page into my Dashboard

Tags: safari, web-browsing, dashboard

I want to store a website in my Dashboard, but the option to do so appears greyed out.

[image]

How do I open the website in Dashboard?

Comment: Please consider sharing a screenshot in with system language set as English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Dashboard is turned off in your system. Go to System Preferences → Mission Control and enable Dashboard by selecting either **As Space** or **As Overlay** corresponding to Dashboard.

[image]

The **Open in Dashboard...** option is unavailable in File menu in Safari if the Dashboard is turned off.